# Appen to variable in for loop

Tags: bash

I need to store `vk`,`pr`,`ns` to `sdout` in for loop. I tried `+=` but i have following error `./script05.sh: line 22: +=: command not found`

```
sdout=
sderr=
for a in "$1"/*
do
    vk=$(egrep ".*" $a -s|wc -c )
    pr=$(egrep "^[a-z ]+$" $a -s| wc -l)
    ns=$(echo $a | sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)/\1/")
    $sdout += "$vk $ns"'\t'"$pr"'\n'
    echo $vk
    if [ $pr -eq 0 ]
    then
        $sderr += "$ns"'\t'"nie"'\n'

    else
        $sderr += "$ns"'\t'"ano"'\n'
    fi
done
```

Comment: The error seems to belong to a very old bash version 3.0 or similar. So: Are you using bash? If true: what version?

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.42(1)-release` is my version

Comment: Then, the script you present has no relation to the error you are asking about. Please edit your question to ask about the error with which you are having trouble and the exact script that caused such error.

Comment: Ahhh, this is the problem: `$sdout +=`. By that point the variable `sdout` has no value and is expanded to null. Thus: the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for « <strike>$sdout</strike> += "value" » should be:

```
sdout+="value"
```

Or fully corrected:

```
sdout+="$vk $ns"'\t'"$pr"'\n'
```

No spaces around the `+=` operator.
That's assuming what you want is to change the variable `sdout`.

The same apply to the other two lines with `$sderr += "$ns"'\t'"nie"'\n'`.
They should be:

```
sderr+="$ns"'\t'"nie"'\n'
sderr+="$ns"'\t'"ano"'\n'
```

Comment: `script05.sh: line 22: +=ol\tnie\n: command not found` after deleting spaces

Comment: @VladimírFencák Are you removing the `$` in front of the variable name????? . Do not use `$sdout+=`

Comment: @sorontar `$` is used to *get* the value of a variable, not when setting it. BTW, [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) is good at spotting mistakes like this.

Comment: D'oh! I meant to address my comment to @VladimírFencák. Sorry.